# How to keep a local service running in between tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-service-binding, fragment-lifecycle

I am currently working on a Pedometer application. At first, I started with one activity, the PedometerActivity. This activity started the service that is supposed to run in the background, and binds to it. The code is long so I'll just give sections of what I think will help in my question.

```
//Bind service
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            //binder to communicate with the service
            PedometerService.PedometerBinder mBinder = (PedometerService.PedometerBinder)service;

            mPedometerService = mBinder.getService();
            mPedometerService.registerCallback(mCallback);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mPedometerService = null;
        }
    };

private void startPedometerService() {
        if (!isPedometerService) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Start service");
            isPedometerService = true;

            //start service
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PedometerService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    //Bind to the service
    private void bindPedometerService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Bind service");

        Intent intent = new Intent(PedometerActivity.this, PedometerService.class);
        bindService(intent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE + Context.BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND);
    }

    //close connection with service
    private void unbindPedometerService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Unbind service");
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    }

    //Stop the service that had been started
    private void stopPedometerService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Stop service");
        if (mPedometerService != null) {

            //stop service
            Intent intent = new Intent(PedometerActivity.this, PedometerService.class);
            stopService(intent);

            isPedometerService = false;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        startPedometerService();
        bindPedometerService();


    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
        stopPedometerService();

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindPedometerService();
        stopPedometerService();        

    }
```

In the service class that extends Service

```
 /*Local service binding*/
    public class PedometerBinder extends Binder {
        public PedometerService getService() {
            return PedometerService.this;
        }
    }


    /*A client is binding to the service with bindService()
    * Returns the IBinder object received in
     * ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(ComponentName,IBinder)*/
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new PedometerBinder();
    }
```

I then modified my application to have tablayout with 3 tabs hence 3 fragments. I pasted the code from PedometerActivity into PedometerFragment and modified it

```
//Bind service
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            //binder to communicate with the service
            PedometerService.PedometerBinder mBinder = (PedometerService.PedometerBinder)service;

            mPedometerService = mBinder.getService();
            mPedometerService.registerCallback(mCallback);
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mPedometerService = null;
        }
    };

private void startPedometerService() {
        if (!isPedometerService) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Start service");
            isPedometerService = true;

            //start service
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    PedometerService.class);
            getActivity().startService(intent);
        }
    }

    //Bind to the service
    private void bindPedometerService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Bind service");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PedometerService.class);
        getActivity().bindService(intent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE + Context.BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND);
    }

    //close connection with service
    private void unbindPedometerService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Unbind service");
        getActivity().unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    }

    //Stop the service that had been started
    private void stopPedometerService() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Stop service");
        if (mPedometerService != null) {

            //stop service
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PedometerService.class);
            getActivity().stopService(intent);

            isPedometerService = false;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();

        startPedometerService();
        bindPedometerService();


    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
        stopPedometerService();

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        unbindPedometerService();
        stopPedometerService();        

    }
```

The problem is am having trouble keeping the service running when I switch between tabs. I am using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** and therefore when I navigate to the last tab, the first fragment (PedometerFragment) is unloaded. I have been able to save other variables in **onSaveInstanceState** but this does not seem to help since everything is restarted all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind service in the `Activity` class. Then you can use it from any attached `Fragment` via interface or public methods.

Comment: Yep, that worked out quite well, Fragment lifecycle methods did not interruot the service

Comment: Fragment lifecycle methods DID interrupt the service (you said so yourself)

Comment: Your override of fragment lifecycle methods*

Answer (score 1):

You're using `startService`, so even if your bound components get destroyed, the service shouldn't be stopped. However, you're explicitly calling `stopPedometerService()` in `onStop()`, which is called when your fragment is no longer started.

Try simply removing `stopPedometerService()` from `onStop()` and`onDestroy()` in your fragments.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to
>   the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the
>   saved state of that fragment.

Comment: I removed stopService method call in onStop and the service was not interrupted, though more problems came up. @Stanislav Bondar solution is the best. The implementation of FragmentStatePagerAdapter was independent of the problem. Thanks

Comment: Stanislav's solution isn't actually the solution... You wanted to know why your service was getting stopped and I showed you that.You don't "need" to bind to the activity either.

Comment: I did miss that you had stopPedometerService in your onDestroy() too, so I updated my answer

Comment: @facilitator What where the "more problems" that came up?